# how to make my own table datatable

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've created my own table with the search funtion wich works with javascript Jquery but the results appear in another place. I've tried to make my html table datatable but I failed :( 
Can anyone tell me how to make a dynamic table to make the live search without using the datatables , which are difficult to customize the styles.

If there is no other way but using datatables , how can I change the style of the table to use my own style ? I mean using my own searchbox not their.

My scripts that I have used is :

```
<script type="text/javascript" > 
      function getSearch(value) {
          $.post("?", {partialState:value},function(data) {
              $('#results').html(data);
          });
        }
</script>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```